# Ordinal position of repetitive values

Tags: mysql

It is more of abstract question. For example, a table

| **animal** |

| cat    |

| dog    |

| dog    |

| cat    |

| cat    |

| dog    |

What I want to retrieve is

| **animal** | **pos** |

| cat    | 1   |

| dog    | 1   |

| dog    | 2   |

| cat    | 2   |

| cat    | 3   |

| dog    | 3   |

Of course, animals are not restricted to cats and dogs and repetitions could go larger.

Any directions where to look would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What's your abstract PK?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select animal,
 case animal
        when 'cat' then @cat:=@cat+1
        when 'dog' then @dog:=@dog+1
 end as animal_row_num
from animals,
     ( select @cat:=0, @dog:=0 ) animal_row_nums
```

***MySQL Fiddle***: [***Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bc94/1)

Comment: Thanks! That would do it for two animals. But what if there were 10000  animals?

Comment: Then, you should not use such report generation at plain DB query level but a stored procedure or a scripting language.

Comment: I know how to do it in php, but that would take weeks on big tables. I wanted to create another column which would hold than value. So I thought there was an easier way. I'll take a look at stored procedures and either accept your answer or update the question.

Comment: You certainly do not need to create a variable for each entity - but you do need a PK